# ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad active but not working in debian jessie

Tags: touchpad

I have a new Toshiba Satellite Harman/kardon which the Touchpad suddenly stopped working.

The touchpad is (ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad)
I have tried so many solutions but nothing seems to work, actually in the Mouse and Touchpad settings I can see the Optical UBS Mouse and the ETPS/2 Elantec enabled, but only the USB Mouse work.

Here are the details:

- No X11 cursor shows up. I'm running debian jessie with kernel  3.16.0-4-amd64.
- I Have tried many key combinations with Fn F5 and other.
- My touchpad is both recognized and enabled my synaptic    touchpad
  package is fully updated a usb mouse works, which I'm using    right
  now
- I don't have an xorg.conf file In my Synaptics package manager I searched toshiba and enabled:-toshset, -acpi-support, -acpitool as I saw in other post.
- I tried disabling and enabling: synclient TouchpadOff=0

**My  xinput list**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Elantech Touchpad                    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Please help, I have months with this new laptop trying to find the best solution, but no success.

I have all this info in my

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    16.642] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[    16.642] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    16.642] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    16.642] Current Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64
(OTHER)
[    18.775] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.775] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    18.775] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    18.775] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    18.775] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    18.775] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    18.775] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.775] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input10/event3"
[    18.775] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    18.775] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.775] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.775] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event4)
[    18.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.776] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[    18.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.776] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event12)
[    18.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.776] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[    18.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.776] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.777] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/event1)
[    18.777] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    18.777] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE'
[    18.777] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: always reports core events
[    18.777] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    18.777] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Vendor 0x93a Product 0x2521
[    18.777] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found 9 mouse buttons
[    18.777] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    18.777] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found relative axes
[    18.777] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found x and y relative axes
[    18.777] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Configuring as mouse
[    18.777] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Adding scrollwheel support
[    18.777] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    18.777] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    18.777] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:093A:2521.0001/input/input7/event1"
[    18.777] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB OPTICAL MOUSE" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[    18.777] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: initialized for relative axes.
[    18.777] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    18.777] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    18.777] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    18.777] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    18.777] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    18.777] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.777] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.777] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD (/dev/input/event8)
[    18.777] (**) TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.777] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD'
[    18.777] (**) TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: always reports core events
[    18.777] (**) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[    18.778] (--) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: Vendor 0x4ca Product 0x705b
[    18.778] (--) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: Found keys
[    18.778] (II) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.778] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input15/event8"
[    18.778] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    18.778] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.778] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.778] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.778] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event14)
[    18.778] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.778] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.778] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event15)
[    18.778] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.778] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.778] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event16)
[    18.778] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.778] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.779] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[    18.779] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.779] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    18.779] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    18.779] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    18.779] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[    18.779] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[    18.779] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.779] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[    18.779] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    18.779] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.779] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.779] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.779] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event2)
[    18.779] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[    18.779] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[    18.779] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[    18.779] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    18.779] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    18.795] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.795]    compiled for 1.16.0.901, module version = 1.8.99
[    18.795]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    18.795]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    18.795] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[    18.795] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[    18.795] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    18.824] (II) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: found clickpad property
[    18.824] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 3260 (res 33)
[    18.824] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 1956 (res 33)
[    18.824] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255
[    18.824] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 0 - 15
[    18.824] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[    18.824] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
[    18.824] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[    18.824] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[    18.824] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[    18.884] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input6/event2"
[    18.884] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[    18.884] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    18.884] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    18.884] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.053
[    18.884] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    18.884] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[    18.884] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    18.884] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    18.884] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[    18.884] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    18.884] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[    18.884] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event7)
[    18.885] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.885] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.885] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Toshiba input device (/dev/input/event6)
[    18.885] (**) Toshiba input device: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.885] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Toshiba input device'
[    18.885] (**) Toshiba input device: always reports core events
[    18.885] (**) evdev: Toshiba input device: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[    18.885] (--) evdev: Toshiba input device: Vendor 0 Product 0
[    18.885] (--) evdev: Toshiba input device: Found keys
[    18.885] (II) evdev: Toshiba input device: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.885] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input13/event6"
[    18.885] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Toshiba input device" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[    18.885] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.885] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.885] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    25.236] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1110
[    25.236] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    25.236] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.32  1366 1414 1446 1610  768 771 776 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    31.290] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1110
[    31.290] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    31.290] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.32  1366 1414 1446 1610  768 771 776 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    44.540] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1110
[    44.540] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    44.540] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.32  1366 1414 1446 1610  768 771 776 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    45.741] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1110
[    45.741] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    45.741] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.32  1366 1414 1446 1610  768 771 776 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
(EE) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Read error 19
[   100.710] (II) config/udev: removing device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
[   100.720] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[   112.186] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event2)
[   112.186] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   112.186] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[   112.186] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[   112.186] (**) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[   112.186] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x1
[   112.186] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found 3 mouse buttons
[   112.186] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found relative axes
[   112.186] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found x and y relative axes
[   112.186] (II) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Configuring as mouse
[   112.186] (**) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   112.186] (**) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   112.186] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input26/event2"
[   112.186] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[   112.186] (II) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: initialized for relative axes.
[   112.187] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   112.187] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   112.187] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   112.187] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   112.187] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   112.187] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   112.187] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   118.032] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1110
[   118.032] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   118.032] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.32  1366 1414 1446 1610  768 771 776 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[   473.862] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1110
[   473.862] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   473.862] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.32  1366 1414 1446 1610  768 771 776 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
```

Comment: Hi there, could anyone help me with this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I get it working now...

What I did:

I followed this link: wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad

There I found the tip in this lines:

> At start, Xorg reads vendor-supplied configuration commands from
>   directory /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d (details in man xorg.conf.d).
>
> If you want to override the defaults system-wide, use a file in
>   /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d, e.g. /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/synaptics.conf, for
>   configuration (but this will work just as well in a combined
>   /etc/X11/xorg.conf file). /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d contains
>   distro-supplied samples which can be copied over (or at least keep an
>   eye on their settings when creating your own configuration). The
>   following example shows how to enable tapping and how to configure
>   various other options; you probably won't need everything in it.
>   Comment out any old config for synaptics before replacing it with this
>   new config.

I noted that I did not have a xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/ directory, so I touched to create it.

after that I copied the configuration I found in the same page:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Touchpad" # required
MatchIsTouchpad "yes" # required
Driver "synaptics" # required
Option "MinSpeed" "0.5"
Option "MaxSpeed" "1.0"
Option "AccelFactor" "0.075"
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "TapButton2" "2" # multitouch
Option "TapButton3" "3" # multitouch
Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1" # multitouch
Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1" # multitouch
Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"
Option "CoastingSpeed" "8"
Option "CornerCoasting" "1"
Option "CircularScrolling" "1"
Option "CircScrollTrigger" "7"
Option "EdgeMotionUseAlways" "1"
Option "LBCornerButton" "8" # browser "back" btn
Option "RBCornerButton" "9" # browser "forward" btn
EndSection
```

I restarted the laptop and "voila" Touch Pad was working again.

Comment: that didnt work for me :/

Comment: Thanks! This indeed worked for me! But, the touchpad is not smooth though!

Comment: This also worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/770340/738143